# open vimeo app in my Android app?

Tags: android, vimeo

I need to show a Vimeo video in my app, I tried it opening the  url in a webview, the url appears, but when I link the play button, the player doesn't work. So I want to try it opening the video with the Vimeo app, but I don't know how to call to Vimeo app from my app.
Can Anybody help me please? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if this will help. but have a look at this code: http://code.google.com/p/vimeoid/source/browse/apk/?r=85e18485bdda1c526141170f67e65f4e00202f34#apk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: thank you, i've found the scheme, i'm going to try it, anyway I've tried vimeo android app and it works awful...

Comment: If you found the solution. post it as an answer here so other can see it in the future :)

Comment: [take a look. This is my solution.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403848/play-vimeo-video-for-android/27194929#27194929

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To launch video in fullscreen with official Vimeo app `com.vimeo.android.videoapp`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+ADD_VIDEO_ID_HERE)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [How to send a link to Vimeo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787253/how-to-send-a-link-to-vimeo/36288433#36288433)

We've built a simple library that can take care of this for you. Here is the [open source github](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-deeplink-android).

`compile 'com.vimeo.android.deeplink:vimeo-deeplink:1.0.0'`

The README will go into more detail, but this is what you'll want to use:

`boolean handled = VimeoDeeplink.showVideoWithUri(Context context, String videoUri)`