# How to play Vimeo Video in Android app

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api

Is there any way to play Vimeo Video in `WebView` or `VideoView` in Android. Any source code for playing Vimeo will be helpful for me. Please help.

Comment: Here is issue link https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:101891 This solution isn't stable but maybe you can use: https://github.com/droid28/VimeoVideo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348

Answer (score 4):

Add WebView to your layout

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp" />
```

Then add

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   webView1.loadData("<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+VIDEO_ID+"\" width=\"180px\" height=\"180px\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>", "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Comment: Instead of using width and height as static values, I believe is better to use `width=\"100%\" height=\"95%\"`

Comment: But this shows the URL of the video if any error occurs. How to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46763314/5829679)

```
mViewHolder.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String yourData = "<div id='made-in-ny'></div>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<script src='https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js'></script>\n" +
            "<script>\n" +
            "    var options = {\n" +
            "        id: 59777392,\n" +
            "        width: 540,\n" +
            "        loop: true\n" +
            "    };\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    var player = new Vimeo.Player('made-in-ny', options);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    player.setVolume(0);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    player.on('play', function() {\n" +
            "        console.log('played the video!');\n" +
            "    });\n" +
            "</script>";

mViewHolder.webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

change id and width. it is working.