# How to play "Vimeo" video in android application?

Tags: android, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

Can anyone tell how to play a vimeo video simply in my android application?

Comment: There is a sample app given here on how to play Vimeo video: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/tree/develop/example-java-android

Comment: check this  post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15403848/1199154

Comment: Try it : https://github.com/ct7ct7ct7/Android-VimeoPlayer