# How to send a link to Vimeo?

Tags: android, eclipse, vimeo, vimeo-android

How can I send a link from the application that I'm doing now to a specific URL?

```
 blah.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705?"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I couldn't write it simpler than that :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url

Comment: I'm not sure if that was not for vimeo

Comment: Vimeo, Youtube, whatever. What's how you open a link in the Android browser. A link is a link. It's handled by the browser. If you are asking how to open a link in the Vimeo Android app, please refer to the documentation for that app.

Comment: So that's it I believe, I;ll apply it in a few :) (Edited)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: Ok, I can't understand 50%! Can you write me the code? Please?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to open the Vimeo URL in the Vimeo Android application, you can either do as you posted, or you can intent out to the Vimeo application with the correct intent data (a.k.a. deep linking). To help facilitate both of these intent types, you can use the [vimeo-deeplink-android](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-deeplink-android) library.

For the above video https://www.vimeo.com/83178705 you have two options:

```
VimeoDeeplink.openUrl(getApplicationContext(), "https://www.vimeo.com/83178705");

VimeoDeeplink.showVideoWithUri(getApplicationContext(), "/videos/83178705");
```

For the latter request, you could re-write it as:

```
VimeoDeeplink.showVideoWithUri(getApplicationContext(), VimeoDeeplink.VIMEO_VIDEO_URI_PREFIX + "83178705");
```

These requests will all open the Vimeo Android application (if installed) and launch the video player.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it when I get my PC.